# Deploying maven liferay project to remote Jboss based Liferay portal

Tags: jboss7.x, maven-3, liferay-6

I'm new with Liferay portal.
here is my config

--Liferay 6.1 deployed on JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final
--Maven 3.1.1

I can easily deploy my portlet(maven project) in local Liferay instance
but i'm trying to deploy this portlet to a remote instance

here is a part of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
  <liferay.version>6.1.2</liferay.version>
  <liferay.parent.server>C:\DEV\Env\JBoss</liferay.parent.server>
<liferay.auto.deploy.dir>${liferay.parent.server}\deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
<liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>${liferay.parent.server}\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments</liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>
<liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>${liferay.parent.server}\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com\liferay\portal\main</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
<liferay.app.server.portal.dir>${liferay.parent.server}\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\ROOT.war</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
...
</build>
```

I would  " liferay.parent.server " to target the remote directory something like 192.168.1.2/Env/JBoss

I have been working on for a long time 
i will really appreciate your helps

Thank you

Comment: did you solve this? i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the **Remote IDE Connector** plugin to the remote instance of Liferay portal.
There are both [CE version](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15193785) and [EE version](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15099066)

Now you can deploy it via your Eclipse: [tutorial](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-liferay-ides-remote-server-adapter)

Or you can use [Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/technopolis/liferay-deployer), but be aware [this issue](https://github.com/technopolis/liferay-deployer/issues/1) (you need to download the source, fix it, and build it)

Answer (score 0):

I remember that Liferay not support remote connector for JBoss.You can see this documents regard [enter link description here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html) Maven plugin for JBoss.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can do remote deploy by maven plugin. You can read this guide http://www.dontesta.it/blog/en/blog-2/cms/liferay/liferay-maven-come-fare-il-deploy-remoto-dei-plugin/

In this article we will see a possible solution for remotely deploying the artifact of a Liferay project based on the maven

The plugin maven wagon-maven-plugin (or wagon) is what will allow you copy the WAR of our portlet on the remote server and then the hot deployment of Liferay (of which I recommend reading the hot deployment versus auto deploy) will carry out the actual installation. Listing 1 shows the wagon plugin configuration included within the plugins section of our project pom.

```
 <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <configuration>
         <fromDir>${project.build.directory}/</fromDir>
         <includes>*.war</includes>
         <url>scp://${jboss.deploy.username}:${jboss.deploy.password}@${jboss.deploy.hostname}/</url>
         <toDir>${jboss.deploy.liferay.dir}</toDir>
    </configuration>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).